# Does the visual object in the storyboard canvas serves as both controllers and views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller

**Background (About MVC)**

What is the clean boundary between the Controller and Views in IOS development?

**Issue via Example**

`MyListController` is my own controller which is build upon the `UITableViewController` (`class MyListController: UITableViewController { ... }` ). In the interface builder (IB) of the StoryBoard a Table View Controller object is dragged into the canvas from the object library. Next, the controller in the IB is connected to the swift source code **MyListController.swift**. This is a standard process to use the table views in development

Assumption 1: the table view object in the IB and the source code it connects to (**MyListController.swift**) all together is called the controller. Views are invisible at the moment, views only come into life when the app runs

Assumption 2: the IB table view object and the **MyListController.swift** is the controller and the IB table view object itself contains the views. The views are presented into the view representatives in the design time (ex image view dragged from the object library), the controller communicated to the views through those view representatives when the app runs

**Question**

Which assumption of mine is close to correct? if not please point out any errors

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no clear boundaries in `MVC`, since it is not really an exact thing, it is just a design pattern with guidelines.

However, in general each element of the UI is considered to be part of the `View` regardless of where you create them. If you only use `Storyboard`, your `View` will be in `Storyboard`, but if you add UI elements to your UI from code, that part of the code will be part of your `View` as well.

Controller is usually considered to be the logic behind your `View`. Namely, the data structures/variables used as data sources to feed your UI with data and the logic defining when to show what on the UI.

For more info have a look at [this tutorial on raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach)
 about the `MVC` approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you will open the Storyboards as source. (Right click on .Storyboard and open as source code). You will realise what is happening here.

Storyboards are nothing but XML files. Which define the various views, their hierarchies, there connection to the code, sizes and constraints if any.

When you run the app depending upon the requirement (which view needs to be presented) the system brings the Storyboard components to life. So the a viewController which is connected to storyboard would be created using its Scene from Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to tell you how I see it:

The .storyboard or .xib files, are just XML data files (as is described in a precious answer) and they represent the view hierarchy and associated data, constraints and definitions. One of those definitions is the class name of the view in question. In case there is a view controller element on the storyboard on in the xib, it is also associated with a class name. Based on the class names and class definitions (in particular @IBOutled and @IBAction markers), Interface Builder "knows" what sort of connections could be made.

So, when you call, say, UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:), the data file is loaded and parsed and view hierarchy is reproduced by creating objects with the specified class names and assigning them values recorded in the data file (see NSCoding.init(coder:)). UIViewController object is instantiated in the same fashion.

In other words, Interface Builder is not producing objects, but a set of instructions for recreating a hierarchy of UIView's and associating them with a UIViewController object, which is created based on a class name.

As for MVC, in documentation and videos, Apple insists on using good MVC practices such as not storing data in views, but as is usually the case with limited systems used for solving unlimited number of problems, such advice is not always strictly followed. That said, when using UIKit, in most cases, you can easily achieve separation between data, logic and presentations layers.

I hope this sheds dome light on the topic but let me know if you have questions.